# HttpContext.Current represents the current context of a user... what is meant by current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

`HttpContext.Current` returns an `IPrincipal` object that represents security context of the current user. I understand principal object combines the identity of a user with other information, such as roles, privileges etc.

But why do we say it represents the **current context** of the user? Why not just say it represent a user? Is there a particular reason why we use the term **current context**?

Comment: Well, actually its core role is to provide the currently thread associated HttpContext, and a HttpContext is everything around the http request and its response- this includes authentication.. not only does it provide access to these things, but it factors in an important fact in asp.net, that a request can start on thread A, and finish on thread B.. meaning that thread static alone wouldn't be enough to uniquely identify the a request and its response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HttpContext object contains access to many other helpful items, such as the Server object that provides the ability to map paths to physical and other paths.  There is much more than user information.

It is the true Context of the HTTP request as it currently stands.  This has request, response, and other objects available as well.

Comment: "Context of the HTTP session" - more accurately, the context of the current HTTP request.